# Editing a tmap data file in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sf, tmap

I'm new to using tmap. I'm using the default "World" map and I'm able to create a world map and color all the countries according to life expectancy simply using:

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("life_exp")
```

But now, I've created my own dataframe to merge with the World dataframe.

```
World2 <- merge(World, df, by="iso_a3")
```

This works and I now have a nice merged dataframe that includes my variables. But when I got to run it, I get this:

```
Error: Object World2 is neither from class sf, stars, Spatial, Raster, nor SpatRaster.
```

Is there something special I need to do to the merged dataframe to make it work here?

Comment: Try step 8.1 here: https://rpubs.com/quarcs-lab/tutorial-maps-in-r (but also look at merge in step 8).

Comment: @user2619203, I see in step 8 they mention converting it to sf using st_as_sf() as opposed to st_sf() mentioned by lovalery below. I just tried and both work--thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your `dataframe` into a `sf` type object. I guess the following line should solve your problem :

`World2 <- st_sf(World2)`

Comment: that worked like a charm-thanks! I used World2 <- st_sf(merge(df, World, by="iso_a3"))

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Please mark the answer as accepted to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. Cheers